# Multiple sessions in single browser

Tags: java

Is it possible to maintain two sessions in a single browser for the same application? Can we handle this issue through code or else we can handle this only through browser.please share your answers

Answer (score 3):

This is possible through session tracking methods like,

- URL binding
- Creating an hidden input field

You can't do this with storing the session id in cookies.

Comment: Indeed, in most of the app servers it is possible disable the session cookie and preserve the session using HttpServletResponse *encodeURL* (that is just an example which could work out of box)